# Sync only specific folders relevant to an android device using Dropbox android sync api

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to develop an android app which uses dropbox sync api.
I will be installing the app on many android devices (say 100 tablets) . 
According to the android api sync documentation , the whole app folder would be shared with all the app instances installed in each of the 100 tablets but i want each device to access only particular sub folder (relevant for a particular device) in the app folder. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

First, to clarify, when using the app folder permission on the Dropbox API, the content of the app folder will only be shared across instances of the app that are linked to the same user account. Different users will not see each other's files. If every device is linked to the same account in this case though, they would all see the same content.

However, the API doesn't provide more granular permissions than this, so it's not possible to restrict different devices to different sub-folders.